# How can I install package on client machine using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and setup a ansible server. I have also set up ssh communication between one client server and client. Now I am able to use few of ansible modules from server in order to make changes in the client one. Ping, Copy modules are working fine.

But when I am trying to install a package from ansible server to the client system using "yum" command it is not working. I am using the below command in order to execute the yum as sudo on my client machine.

Command:

```
ansible all -m yum -a "name=httpd state=present" -s
```

This command is throwing an error that -s is unidentified . Request you to please help me in this case.

Comment: Don;t you get to combine `-s` with `-u USER`?

Comment: I am configured the ansible user in client machine as sudo.

Comment: Strange. "*-s*" is deprecated (will be removed in version 2.9). Instead of an error, you should have seen the warning. Please post the full output of the command. What Ansible version are you running?

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladimir for your response. I am using ansible version 2.8.0.                                                When I am using the command without -s it's throwing following error.  
    "msg": "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)\nE: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/\nW: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin --             
While trying to run the command as sudo on client machine (-s at the end) it's saying "ansible:error:No such option". Could you please help me with this.     Many thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need replace -s with -b
sudo module was replaced by become module, but it does the same

```
tenhi@somehost:somedir$ ansible localhost -b -m yum -a 'name=mc state=present'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "pkg_mgr": "apt"
    },
    "cache_update_time": 1557517026,
    "cache_updated": false,
    "changed": false
}
```